# LINQ Query descending tree

Tags: c#, linq

I have this entity structure:

Categories->**Has many** "Groups"->**Has many** "Types"->**Has many** "Items"

I need to get the descending tree (with **includes**) filtering by **Item.Color == "blue"**, that is:

```
var tree = from c in db.Categories
                       .Include(ct =>
                                ct.Groups
                                  .Select(gr =>
                                          gr.Types
                                            .Select(pr => pr.Products)
                                         )
                               )
           join g in db.Groups on c.CategoryId equals g.CategoryId
           join t in db.Types on g.GroupId equals t.GroupId
           join i in db.Items on t.TypeId equals i.TypeId
           where i.Color == "blue" // example filter
           select c;
```

With this query I have the descending tree, however I get Items with other colors.

**I need only descending tree for blue items.**

Thanks!

Comment: I cant see why you need the `include` when you "include" those tables already in the join.

Comment: Is this EntityFramework Linq2Entities? or LinqToObjects?

Comment: Thanks @paqogomez, Any suggestions, How would you do?

Comment: @MichalCiechan is EF Code First.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using EntityFramework.

All you need to do is an include all the way down, and then use the .Any predicate on your entities. E.g.

```
var tree = db.Categories.Include(ct => ct.Groups.Select(gr =>
                                          gr.Types.Select(pr => 
                                             pr.Products)))
           .Where(c => c.Groups.Any(g => 
                         g.Types.Any(t => 
                           t.Items.Any(i => 
                             i.Color == "blue"))))
           .ToList()
```

A word of warning, if a type has multiple items, and only 1 is blue, you will get all of its Items,  not just the blue one. But if a type has no blue items, you wont get it.

If you want to filter at each level, you will need to do projections at each level.

**EDIT**

So if you want to filter you have 2 options:

1. Projection at each level
2. Start by getting all blue items, and then retrieve theirs types, groups and categories.

Examples

### 1. Projections at each level

```
var tree = db.Categories.Include(ct => ct.Groups.Select(gr =>
                                          gr.Types.Select(pr => 
                                             pr.Products)))               
           .Where(c => c.Groups.Any(g => 
                         g.Types.Any(t => 
                           t.Items.Any(i => 
                             i.Color == "blue"))))
           .Select(c => new { Groups = c.Groups.Where(g => 
                                         g.Types.Any(t => 
                                           t.Items.Any(i => 
                                             i.Color == "blue"))
                              .Select( g => new { Types = g.Types.Where(t => 
                                           t.Items.Any(i => 
                                             i.Color == "blue"))
                                                  .Select(t => new { Items = t.Items.Where(i => 
                                                                               i.Color == "blue")
           .ToList() // Return list of anonymous types (
```

You cannot project back an entity type, you have to retrieve the annonymous types first, and then use Linq2Objects to project into the Entity type as EF will not allow you to do this. Often what I do is directly project into a view model ready for display.

Comment: Thanks Michal Ciechan. Projections at each level? Can you explain?

Comment: Thanks Michal Ciechan, Good explanation!